# ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49) when configuring Pass-Trough authentication with SASL in OpenLDAP with AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap, authentication, openldap, sasl

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and OpenLDAP-2.4.40. I have synchronized Active Directory users in OpenLDAP using [LSC](http://lsc-project.org/wiki/documentation/start) utility. Now I want to do the authentications on the OpenLDAP part and will use the AD password using Pass-Trough authentication with SASL.

To do this I have followed [this blog](http://ltb-project.org/wiki/documentation/general/sasl_delegation). After performing all the steps mentioned in this blog, I have fired the below command in command line to fetch user details:

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.example.com -D uid=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com -w password -b CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com
```

but after that I am getting:

> ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)

even though credentials are correct. There are no logs in the log file to debug the issue.

Comment: Please don't cross post, questions can be migrated to a more suitable SE site if off-topic or unsuitable (or delete [your question from SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589822/ldap-bind-invalid-credentials-49-when-configuring-pass-trough-authentication) if you don't want to wait for your question to be migrated)

Comment: You might want to take a look at your log files first (maybe after increasing the [loglevel]("http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconfig.html#loglevel <level>")) and post any errors/warnings you get